# Как передать метод get в ссылку

Tags: php, php7

Как передать в ссылку метод get и что бы при нажатии появлялась определенная информация.

```
<form method="get">
  <a href="index.php?mainLink">main link</a>
</form>

<?php
   echo "information";
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="index.php?someValue=123">main link</a>
```

```
$someValue = $_GET['someValue'] ?? null;

if (isset($someValue)) { 
    echo $someValue; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ну так просто в параметр передайте значение. 
А на странице уже работайте с ним.

```php
<?php
$id = "123";
?>


<form method="get">
    <a href="index.php?mainLink='<?php echo $id;?>">main link</a>
</form>

<?php
echo "information";
?>
```